# Wordpress menu not displaying all menu item on some pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have searched for a while and cannot find anything specific to my issue.

I have a WordPress site that I added a new menu item, it does not display on some pages and others it does.

here is the site:
http://www.allproplumbers.com/

the 4th menu item under Plumbing should be Water Heater Brands as it is on the [Plumbing](http://www.allproplumbers.com/ontario-and-riverside-plumbers.htm) page.

I don't get it, its the same menu or should be on ALL pages.
Even inspecting the element doesnt show it.

Sorry if this post doesn't contain enough information, i just don't know what else to post in it.
I don't have any cache plugins, I use the Swell Template (and yes, I checked there) but everything is about making it show the menu on certain pages, I need ALL menu items on ALL pages.

If there is something else I can post to clear this issue, I will post it.

as requested, header and footer code:

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title><?php wp_title(' &#187; ', true); ?></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo_theme_dir('parent') ?>/favicon.png" />
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="sdUWtQY93zlQ0vEZ-gkNKX9ZAMRop4uUuMiR5v3ar6Y" />
<?php   
    wp_register_style( 'slbase', get_theme_dir('parent') . "/css/base.css" );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slbase' );       
?>  
<?php   
    wp_register_style( 'sldefault', get_theme_dir('parent') . "/css/default.css" );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'sldefault' );        
?>
<?php   
    wp_register_style( 'style', get_theme_dir('parent') . "/style.css" );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );        
?>
<?php   
    wp_register_style( 'cstyle', get_theme_dir('parent') . "/custom.css" );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'cstyle' );       
?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<?php load_google_font('Asap:400,700'); ?>  
<?php load_google_font('Droid+Sans'); ?>    
<?php include_once(get_template_directory().'/inc/options.php'); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<header id="header" class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo left">
        <?php if($swell_opt['logo'] == null): ?>
            <div id="logo"><a href="<?php echo (site_url()); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> Home"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></div>
            <h3 id="tagline" class="alt"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h3>
        <?php else: ?>
            <a title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" href="<?php echo (site_url()); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $swell_opt['logo']; ?>" alt=""/></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>  
        <?php if($swell_opt['call_us_banner'] !== ''): ?>
            <?php echo $swell_opt['call_us_banner']; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>  
</header>
<nav id="nav" class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <?php get_template_part('parts/mobile-menu'); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('parts/top-bar'); ?>
        <a href="#requestcallback-hide" class="request-call"><img src="<?php echo get_theme_dir('parent'); ?>/images/request-callback.png" alt=""/></a>
    </div>
</nav>
<?php if(is_page('home')):?>
<div class="slider-container">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider home-slider]'); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

footer.php

```
                <?php global $swell_opt; ?>
            <footer id="footer" class="footer-container">
                <div class="row footer-top">
                    <div class="container common">  
                        <div class="col-3-12">
                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Footer', 'menu-class' => '') ); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3-12">
                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Footer Right', 'menu-class' => '') ); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6-12" id="contact-us">
                            <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="64" title="Footer Form"]'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>                               
                </div>
                <div class="row footer-bottom">
                    <div class="container common copyright">
                        <div class="credit">
                            <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_theme_dir('parent'); ?>/images/bbb.png" alt=""/></a>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="social-media">
                            <?php if($swell_opt['facebook'] !== ''): ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $swell_opt['facebook']; ?>" class="fb" title="Facebook"></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if($swell_opt['twitter'] !== ''): ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $swell_opt['twitter']; ?>" class="twitter" title="Twitter"></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if($swell_opt['google_plus'] !== ''): ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $swell_opt['google_plus']; ?>" class="gplus" title="Google Plus"></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
            <p>All Pro Plumbing Services 5075 E Airport Drive Ontario CA 91761</p>
            <br>
                        <?php echo $swell_opt['copyright']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
            <div id="requestcallback-hide" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
              <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="410" title="Request a Callback"]'); ?>
            </div>
            <div id="requestqoute-hide" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
              <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="411" title="Request a Quote"]'); ?>
            </div>
            <div id="schedule-service-form" class="white-popup-large mfp-hide">
                <h2 class="center">Schedule a Service</h2>
                <iframe src="http://www.allproplumbers.com/request-free-estimate.htm" width="100%" height="1250" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://form.jotform.us/jsform/xxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>-->
            </div> 
            <?php
                // load scripts 
                wp_deregister_script('jquery');
                wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js', false, false, true);
            ?>
            <?php wp_enqueue_script( 'slcommon', get_theme_dir('parent') . '/js/common.js', array('jquery'), false, true ); ?>
            <?php wp_footer(); ?>
            <script>
              (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
              (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
              m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
              })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
              ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
              ga('send', 'pageview');
            </script>
            <!-- Google Code for Website Form Conversion Page -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
            /* <![CDATA[ */
            var google_conversion_id = xxxxxxxx;
            var google_conversion_language = "en";
            var google_conversion_format = "3";
            var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
            var google_conversion_label = "wUWSCNvBvF4Q1eDr4AM";
            var google_remarketing_only = false;
            /* ]]> */
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
            </script>
            <noscript>
            <div style="display:inline;">
            <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/xxxxxxxxx/?label=wUWSCNvBvF4Q1eDr4AM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
            </div>
            </noscript>
            </body>
```

I am editing once again because the site asked me not to comment too much but turn it into chat, but i dont have privs to chat.

So i had a friend in another state load the site, it showed up where it was supposed to, however, he refreshed the page, now its gone.

Which immediately made me think of cookies, but like i said before, there are no cache plugins on the site, could there be a cookie plugin or something that i cant see? @ham-sandwich if you refresh the home page now that it is in your cache, does it still show?

Comment: post the code for **header.php** and **footer.php** please.

Comment: @ham-sandwich done, i edited the original post

Comment: Hmm, it is showing up for me on every page and I can't see anything in your code that would cause it to function differently. Have you tried emptying your browser cache?

Comment: Several times, my client is the one that brought it to my attention when i told him i posted the new content, then i couldn't see it either. I will try clearing again with all browsers closed (sometimes i have several windows of Chrome open at once) and see if it still happens.

Comment: Try opening an incognito window in Chrome and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Restarted in safe mode, cleared cache, ran scans, still not showing, opened in IE, Chrome Incognito, even Firefox, still do not see it on the home page